# Multiple joins behaving differently in where condition in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
$materials = Material::find()
    ->where(['in', 'Material.MaterialId', $value])
    ->joinWith(['objectName'])
    ->all();

$product = Product::find()
    ->where(['Product.productId' => $id, 'Product.ModelId' => $mid])
    ->joinWith(['product' => function ($query) {
        $query->joinWith([
            'objectName',
            'contents' => function ($query2) {
                $query2->joinWith(['material' => function ($query3) {
                    $query3->where(['in', 'Material.MaterialId', $value])
                        ->joinWith(['objectName']);
                }]);
            },
        ])
        ->all();
    }])
    ->one();
```

I ran into an error. `$query3` gives an error that `IN` expects two operands while if I supply the same material model it's working fine but in Product model it's not working.

Moreover I want to add products to cart products and its addons (I call them in material object). If I rewrite my `$query3` as

```
$query3->where(['in','Material.MaterialId', ['ID1', 'ID2']])->joinWith(['objectName']);
```

It's working in a way it supposed to be. Also If I use `ArrayHelper::toArray($value)` It returns me `null`, Might be because the `$value` array is now subarray. I am sure that the `$value` is array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$value` does not exist within the scope of the closure it is referenced in. Each closure is a scope on its own and can only use global variables or those from its parent scope. As such `$value` has to be successively inherited by each closure that is a parent of the closure it is used in. This can be done via [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) :

```
$product = Product::find()
    ->where(['Product.productId' => $id, 'Product.ModelId' => $mid])
    ->joinWith(['product' => function ($query) use ($value) {
        $query->joinWith([
            'objectName',
            'contents' => function ($query2) use ($value) {
                $query2->joinWith(['material' => function ($query3) use ($value) {
```

The same applies for `$query2` and `$query3`.

Comment: I didnt thought it that way, this worked like a charm. thanks a lot. Thanks for reminding the forgotten concepts of variable scope.